# Converting a DTO to a REST request in a SOAP stub

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap, dto

Realising an automatic mapping of DTO input to an API Rest a Stub XML to invoke a SOAP call in Spring Boot 2.5.

In Spring Boot, I am realising an 'Adapter' microservice which interfaces with a REST microservice and a legacy SOAP service. From the WSDL I have generated any stubs to make the SOAP request. My microservice exposes a REST API that takes a DTO as input. I should create a mapper between the DTO it receives from the REST call in the XML stub. How could I do this? Is there a way to generate DTOs from the XML stub in order to have an automatic mapping?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm understanding that you have 2 DTO: RestDto for rest api and SoapDto for soap Api, and you want to convert from RestDto to SoapDto

Why not use the SoapDto for rest api? With this way, you don't have to create rest dto and don't have to map.

If you don't prefer it, you can choose some library that helps you map automatically, ex MapStruct or DozerBean mapper...